# React-chartjs-2 resize problem (it doesnt grow the chart back to normal size)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-chartjs-2

I'm new to using this library and the chart display correctly the only problem is that the chart doesn't grow back when I change it from phone view to normal view here is my code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  BarElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
  ArcElement,
} from 'chart.js';
import { SimpleGrid } from '@mantine/core';
import { Bar, Doughnut, Pie } from 'react-chartjs-2';

ChartJS.register(CategoryScale, LinearScale, BarElement, Title, Tooltip, Legend, ArcElement);
export const options = {
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      position: 'top' as const,
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Nivel de Mantenimiento',
    },
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: true,
  },
};

const GraficaEjempl = ({ chartdata }: any) => (
  <SimpleGrid
    breakpoints={[
      { minWidth: 'sm', cols: 2 },
      { minWidth: 'md', cols: 3 },
      { minWidth: 1200, cols: 3 },
    ]}
  >
    <div>
      <Pie data={chartdata} options={options} />
    </div>
    <div>
      <Bar data={chartdata} options={options} />
    </div>
    <div>
      <Doughnut data={chartdata} options={options} />
    </div>
  </SimpleGrid>
);

export default GraficaEjempl;
```

I have already tried the [Important notes in the website](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/responsive.html#important-note)